# Migrating SP2013 from windows server2008R2 to windows server2012R2 keeping sharepoint version same

Tags: sharepoint-server, administration, farm-admin, migration

I have SharePoint 2013 farm set up on windows server2008R2 and now I want to move that to windows server2012R2. How to do that?

FYI: I have 3 servers in the farm- one for Active Directory, another for SQL and one more for SharePoint2013.

Comment: on new hardware ( i mean new servers)? are you upgrading to AD?

Answer (score 1):

Add a new SharePoint 2013 server (must be SharePoint 2013 w/ SP1 ISO, then update to your current patch level), add it to the farm, start Service Instances as appropriate, then remove your old server from the farm.

Those are the basic steps to swap out a SharePoint server.